# assigning a 32 bit value to unsigned uint8_t array

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have a structure as shown below.

```
typedef struct
{
    attribute_code_t field_id;
    uint8_t instance_num;
    uint8_t length;
    uint8_t data[32];
    uint32_t crc_value;
}table_entry_t;
```

I want to populate the structure as follows.

```
entry->field_id = 54;;
entry->instance_num = 0;
entry->length = 4;
entry->data = 0xfdfcfefa;
```

It is giving me the error,  error: incompatible types in assignment.at the last line.I am wondering what is the best way to do the above assignment.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code copies data to first 4 bytes of 32- byte.

```
tmpdata = 0xfdfcfefa;
memcpy(entry->data, &tmpdata, sizeof(uint8_t) *4);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the 32-byte array and you are trying to assign to them a 4-byte value. What result do you want? If it is filling first 4 bytes, assign them separately. Or use constant array:

```
static const uint8_t __initializer[] = { 0xfd, 0xfc, 0xfe, 0xfa };
entry->length = sizeof(__initializer);
memcpy( entry->data, __initializer, sizeof(__initializer) );
```

It is strongly not recommended to copy int to the array due to various byte order on different platforms.

Comment: Right, you will have to pay attention to byte order problems